# Debugging ruby in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, rubymine-7

I am new to Ruby and RubyMine but I have tried essentially everything I have found online but can't get the debugger to work in RubyMine, keep getting the following error:

`` Error running 'simple_array_sum': Failed to Install Gems. Following gems were not installed: /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/rb/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta9.gem: Error installing ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta9.gem: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. current directory: /Users/ruskindantra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta9/ext /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb Installing base gem Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Library/Ruby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `mkdir' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `fu_mkdir' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:227:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in `reverse_each' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in `block in mkdir_p' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `each' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:691:in `verify_gem_home' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:811:in `pre_install_checks' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:278:in `install' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:97:in `install' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:166:in `block in install' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:156:in `each' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:156:in `install' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:405:in `install' mkrf_conf.rb:35:in `rescue in  ' mkrf_conf.rb:28:in ` ' rake failed, exit code 1 Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ruskindantra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta9 for inspection. Results logged to /Users/ruskindantra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta9/gem_make.out ``

Can anyone please help?

Comment: try https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for @SachinSingh :(

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem: `Installing base gem Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Library/Ruby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `mkdir'`. Can you use a different login that has write privileges for the directory in question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that RubyMine is pointing at the system version of Ruby. I would recommend starting with a Ruby version manager of some sort, such as [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)

From there, you can install a version Ruby under your home directory using the version manager, and then tell RubyMine to point to it (Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems -> [pick the version manager-installed Ruby you installed].

This may be a bit involved if you're just getting started, but it avoids polluting the gems folder of the system version of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

- Updated rubymine with toolbox to the newest version
- Click "debug" on your app once you set up your configuration
- Get the following error message:

  [image]
- Go to the problematic directory (in this case `/Users/lizzie/.gem/ruby/2.7.0`)
- Click "Get Info" on the directory:

  [image]
- Click the lock button on the bottom right and put in your password, give everyone read & write access, and finally click the action menu and select "Apply to enclosed folders":

  [image]